# Consume (JSON or YAML) generated data values in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, yaml

I am trying to find a way to represent data types in JSON or YAML that can be referenced in other JSON/YAML files to define other objects, that can then be processed in a Python file.

Any advice of other technologies that can meet my requirements will also be appreciated.

From my basic understanding:

- JSON schemas let you refer to other JSON schemas via the $ref command, this specifies the types of the field but not the values.
- YAML allows you to use anchors and flags to refer to data values in the SAME file only.

I need a mixture of these.
- To layout my data with members of types defined in other files.
- To be able to access the data the type specifies.

Initially, I have a 3rd party python file with settings and this is subject to change.

For example (ignoring any obvious syntax errors):

**3rdParty.py**

```
alpha.beta.LOW = 1
alpha.beta.MEDIUM = 2
alpha.beta.HIGH = 3
```

from which I autogenerate **vars.json** file:

```
[
  {"LOW" : "alpha.beta.LOW"},
  {"MEDIUM": "alpha.beta.MEDIUM"},
  {"HIGH": "alpha.beta.HIGH"}
]
```

Constructed **foo.json** file

```
[
  "construct_1":
    {"A": "vars.json#/LOW"},
    {"B": "something"},
    {"C": "vars.json#/MEDIUM"},
    {"D": "something"},
    {"E": "vars.json#/HIGH"}
  },
  ... construct_2 / construct_3 defined ...
]
```

Constructed **bar.py** file

```
import json

data = json.load('foo.json')
setting = eval(data.construct_1.A)        # resolves to alpha.beta.LOW or 1
```

Is this possible and how?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as JSON is concerned, `"$ref"` is not a command, but just a string. It is the implementation of JSON schema that assigns a semantic to it.

JSON and YAML are languages that describe data structures, no more and no less. They have no commands. If you use them, you can do whatever you want with the loaded data, but you need to implement it yourself. The reason why YAML has anchors and aliases is because it serializes a graph while JSON serializes a tree.

YAML provides *tags* which you could use to identify values that need to be replaced, e.g.

```yaml
construct_1:
  A: !ref "vars.json#/LOW"
  B: "something"
  C: !ref "vars.json#/MEDIUM"
  D: "something"
  E: !ref "vars.json#/HIGH"
construct_2: # …
```

As you can see, I marked all values that need to be resolved with the tag `!ref`. Now you need to implement that tag:

```py
def resolve_ref(loader, node):
  path = loader.construct_scalar(node)
  return resolve_path(path)

yaml.add_constructor(u'!ref', resolve_ref)
```

This requires you to implement `resolve_path`. If you do that properly, you can then do

```py
data = yaml.load("foo.yaml")
setting = eval(data["construct_1"]["A"])
```

and it will evaluate whatever `resolve_path` resolved `vars.json#/Low` to.

Comment: Thanks for that. I followed your pattern above and successfully parsed my tag 1-level deep. More testing is required for more depths.
I skimmed the docs but don't understand why they haven't provided this feature by default. Can you provide some information why this is?

Comment: @Dodomac It is simply outside of YAML's scope. Limitation in scope is very important when defining a data format: Too little, and it is of no use; too much, and the effort of implementing it will be so great that no-one does. I once met with other people involved in YAML and we discussed whether to include transformations in YAML 1.3 and I even [implemented a proof-of-concept](https://ada.yaml.io/trans/) but the result was that it is too much of an effort and practically no-one would support it.